# CSV reader incorrectly returns first element of line

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I'm using python to read a CSV file with the following settings:

```
import unicodecsv, ssl    
ctx = ssl._create_unverified_context()
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url, timeout=300, context=ctx)
    data = unicodecsv.reader(response,
                              delimiter=";",
        quotechar="\"",
        doublequote=False,
        quoting=unicodecsv.QUOTE_ALL,
        skipinitialspace=True,
        encoding="utf-8-sig")
```

For this line:

> "ID";"Product";"URL";"Color";"Stock"

it returns:
"ID", Product, URL, Color, Stock

So for the first element in the line, it keeps the quote. I use utf-8-sig because there are BOM characters.

Comment: Instead of showing settings, posting a [example] is more effective.

Comment: I've updated the example with some code.

Comment: Why do you have `skipinitialspace` and `encoding` twice? Removing those, and running it on a `response = io.BytesIO(b'\xef\xbb\xbf' + '"ID";"Product";"URL";","Color";"Stock"'.encode())`, I could not reproduce your error — `list(data)` is `[['ID', 'Product', 'URL', ',Color"', 'Stock']]`.

Comment: Does the use of `unicodecsv` imply you are using Python 2? You should probably say so, and add a corresponding tag if so.

Comment: yes, python 2. @Amadan I've remove the duplication of attributes. I see you also have an error in your result, so could be similar. -> ',Color"'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirmed as bug in unicodecsv for Python2 (see [issue 81](https://github.com/jdunck/python-unicodecsv/issues/81)).

`unicodecsv.UnicodeReader` is not passing along the encoding to the underlying `csv.reader`, so it doesn't know the BOM should be stripped, so the first field doesn't start with the quotechar, and doesn't count as a quoted field.

The issue is at this moment 2.5 years old, the project was last touched 4+ years ago, and seems abandoned (per [issue 92](https://github.com/jdunck/python-unicodecsv/issues/92)). I highly suggest moving away from `unicodecsv`. If you have to use it, read the response yourself into a string, strip BOM, then pass the cleaned up text to `unicodecsv` via `io.StringIO`.

Comment: thanks for finding it for me. I was really close finding this https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/4793#issuecomment-228173518 but yours is more explicit.